# Remove null values from SQL result

Tags: sql, oracle

My Oracle SQL query returns only 1 row.

I want to remove the null values from the result.

I don't want to get an empty column. I want my query to ignore this column.

For example, I have this table and query:

```
create table tbl (col_1 number, 
                  col_2 number, 
                  col_3 number);

insert into tbl values(1,null,3);
commit;

select col_1, col_2, col_3 from tbl where rownum=1;
```

The result is:

> ```
> | COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 |
> +-------+-------+-------+
> | 1     |       | 3     |
> +-------+-------+-------+
> ```

In this case, I want my query to ignore "COL_2" field, and return:

> ```
> | COL_1 | COL_3 |
> +-------+-------+
> | 1     | 3     |
> +-------+-------+
> ```

Comment: Your question as it currently stands doesn't make sense. Please show your real sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hi. I edited my question now. I hope now is more understandable.

Comment: i don't think it is possible,if one column not have the data in first row, but what happened if it has data in 2nd row?

Comment: I assume my query returns only one row

Comment: This doesn't make sense and is not was SQL is used for. Do that in your application if you really need it. Keep in mind the next row could contain a value for column2. "Assuming" is generally not sufficient when writing SQL.

Comment: and if I use "where rownum=1"?

Comment: "And if I do this and that and...". As said, this doesn't make sense, we can just select column1 and column3 only instead.

Comment: SQL result set structure is determined by the query itself, not by any data (which is not available at the query parsing time)..

Comment: Recommendation - *simplify* the interface. Either return a *key - value* cursor (with 1 to 3 rows) or return a JSON column with 1 to 3 attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is a table that contains up to 3 columns in a single row; could be even result of a query, doesn't matter - you'd just fix line #9 in function code.

```
SQL> create table test (a number, b number, c number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (1, null, 3);

1 row created.
```

Function returns refcursor. Why? That's one option to return different columns, depending on `select` statement.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2  return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l1 number;
  5    l2 number;
  6    l3 number;
  7    rc sys_refcursor;
  8  begin
  9    select a, b, c into l1, l2, l3 from test;
 10
 11    if l1 is null and l2 is null and l3 is null then
 12       open rc for select null from dual where 1 = 2;
 13    elsif l1 is not null and l2 is null and l3 is null then
 14       open rc for select l1 from dual;
 15    elsif l1 is not null and l2 is not null and l3 is null then
 16       open rc for select l1, l2 from dual;
 17    elsif l1 is not null and l2 is null and l3 is not null then
 18       open rc for select l1, l3 from dual;
 19    elsif l1 is not null and l2 is not null and l3 is not null then
 20       open rc for select l1, l2, l3 from dual;
 21    elsif l1 is null and l2 is not null and l3 is null then
 22       open rc for select l2 from dual;
 23    elsif l1 is null and l2 is not null and l3 is not null then
 24       open rc for select l2, l3 from dual;
 25     elsif l1 is null and l2 is null and l3 is not null then
 26        open rc for select l3 from dual;
 27    end if;
 28
 29    return rc;
 30  end;
 31  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it: initially, we have A and B:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

       :B2        :B1
---------- ----------
         1          3
```

We have only C:

```
SQL> update test set a = null, b = null, c = 3;

1 row updated.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

       :B1
----------
         3
```

We don't have anything:

```
SQL> update test set a = null, b = null, c = null;

1 row updated.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

no rows selected


SQL>
```

---

Of course, if it gets more complex, code won't be that simple any more and you might find yourself in *maintenance problems*.

Comment: I need to try it. But I don't know if my customer will let me to use function in his DB

Comment: From my point of view, that's not something you should handle in query but in reporting tool you use. For example, if it were Apex, you'd use **condition** and display (or not) column whose value is NULL. But OK; I suggested one option, see if you can use it (or not).

Comment: Yes, never do such things in SQL, this is not what SQL is designed for (and that's the reason why it is nearly impossible to do it at all). Use your application for such things. Generally spoken: If it is nearly impossible to build up something in SQL, it is mostly no good idea to do it anyway. In such cases, the thing just doesn't make sense or should be done using other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot get what you want with pure SQL as you need to specify the columns you want to see in response in your SELECT statement before the execution.

check out the dynamic SQL / refcursors/ pipeline functions:

- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4843682300346852395#5421020800346627246)
- https://blogs.oracle.com/connect/post/how-to-dynamically-change-the-columns-in-a-sql-query

Comment: But I don't know if col_2 contains null or value. In case that it contains some value, I want this value